# is it possible to add tags to kafka connect connectors in AWS MSK

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka

We are using AWS MSK connect "connectors". The cost of these connectors (runconnect API) by far make up the biggest chuck of the overall costs of using MSK in AWS in our case (75%). However, it looks like it is not possible to tag the connectors and therewith assign the cost to certain usergroups or projects.

Am I correct that it is not possible to tag these connectors? (or am I missing something?)

Answer (score 0):

AWS CLI has and command to tag resources for MSK.
[kafka-tag-resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/kafka/tag-resource.html)

try this, let's see if it helps

Answer (score 0):

Alas, it is not possible to tag MSK Connector resources.

[AWS Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/msk-tagging.html) suggest adding tags using separate tagging API. Though, this is related to `aws kafka` ([ref](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/kafka/index.html#cli-aws-kafka)), not `aws kafkaconnect` ([ref](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/kafkaconnect/index.html)) API. Hence, tagging API does not even exist for connectors.